# Only in one of my Xamarin(Portable) Projects the Nuget Package Manager Source gives me an Error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, nuget-package, nugetgallery

I searched a lot and found some question related to my question but my problem occurs just in one of my Xamarin(Portable) projects.

When I try to install or even try to browse for a Nuget Lib, with the Package Source of .Net I get an Error(see pic in link).

So if I create a new Project I do not get any problems.

I assume that I accidentally changes something in my project.

Using VS 2015
Any ideas ???

Thank you :D

[image]

Comment: You might check the `visual studio 2015 -> Tools menu -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Settings`  Then search for the `NuGet Package Manager` item and check the `Package Sources`.. does anything is left out blank?

Comment: Post errors as text, not pictures. We like them to be googlable.

Comment: The picture is not clear.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen i already checked that. Nothing is empty, i mean with other projects it works just fine.

Comment: @HenkHolterman  When select the "nuget.org" package source i works. But if i select All or just "Micorsoft and .Net" i get this the Output form the Package Manger: "[Microsoft and .NET] Invalid portable frameworks."

Answer (score 0):

I solved by deleting the project and checking out my repo again